# Android emulator font smoothing

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, emulation

It is possible to change font smoothing for Adndoid emulator?
I have a Flutter project that worked fine, I reopened after couple months,updated Android Studio/emulator/Flutter and got that ugly display

thanks

[image]